# How to interpret this CAN bus data and find an equation?

Tags: communication, can, reverse-engineering, data-acquisition

I am trying to reverse engineer the data sent from an old CAN bus data logger. It sends a single ID which is selectable from a dip switch.

The only bit of data I am struggling with is the RPM

I plan to feed this data into a STM32F Discovery, in the past most of this type of data is linear and easy to work with, for example RPM=CANbus data x 0.32 but looking at my data below it is not linear and I cannot find a simple way of interpreting it:

RPM      CAN Bus Decimal Data

1000 = 0312

1250 = 0389

1500 = 0464

1750 = 0541

2000 = 0613

2250 = 0688

2500 = 0762

2750 = 0828

3000 = 0903

3250 = 0979

3500 = 1058

3750 = 1140

4000 = 1226

4250 = 1313

4500 = 1401

4750 = 1485

5000 = 1568

5250 = 1653

5500 = 1736

5750 = 1821

6000 = 1900

6250 = 1984

6500 = 2063

6750 = 2144

7000 = 2224

7250 = 2301

7500 = 2377

So I need to come up with an equation so I can put it in my code to calculate the RPM.

RPM = Data x 0.3 + 12 is very close but not close enough

I have plotted the above on a graph and the line of best fit is:
y=0.00000357058x^2+0.29145x+11.9358 but this seems very complicated to try to replicate in code and I also cant see why the designer would have made the data so complicated.

So my question is how can I take the above data and come up with an equation or code so my device can interpret the RPM from the CAN bus data?

Comment: You could program in a lookup table and do a linear interpolation between points.

Comment: where are you getting the RPM values?

Comment: by disconnecting the device from the network and sending my own data to the bus via a usb to can device the rpm is then displayed on the legacy screen

Comment: Let's get this straight. Are you saying that, for instance, if you send decimal 2224 via CAN, the legacy software displays 7000 RPM?

Comment: Yes correct if I send 2224 decimal it displays 7000 RPM on screen

Comment: where are you getting the values from?  .... how do you know that 2224 corresponds to 7000 RPM?

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty linear to me:

[image]

I doubt you have any real work to do.

Comment: Something is wrong with the source data, 4250 and 4500 appear twice with different values.

Comment: My thought exactly ...an offset like that would seem to indicate it's probably quite linear.

Comment: My bad, something went wrong with copy and paste there! Ive now updated the data in the question